# Button onclick() event should not open link

Tags: php, html

This may sound weird, but I want to have a button with a link that does not open when the users clicks it:

```
<a href="http://mysite.nl/test.php?value=snow"> click</a>
```

I want to do this because this link has PHP values to recreate the page. The button is on with a new background colour.

I can't just use

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor='Snow'
```

because the page auto reloads and I want the colour to stay 'snow' even when the page reloads.

Can this be done? Are there better ways to permanently change the style by the click of a button?

Comment: So, it sounds like what you want to do when they click the link is change the query string of the current page so that when it auto-reloads, it will pass the new color.

How are you doing the auto-reload?  Because if it's in a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag, you're out of luck; there's no way to alter that from Javascript.  And the URL is established when the tag is first read; it doesn't change just because the current page's Location does.

Comment: Kinc of a confusing question. Do you want the background to persist when the user reloads the page, or do you want nothing tohappen when the user clicks the button

Comment: I use meta http-equiv="refresh to auto reload. so there is no way then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php SESSION for this

```
$_SESSION['color']='snow';
```

and take the value from from session by each reload.
And use preventDefault() for prevent the link redirection by using javascript

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using hidden fields and have the background as the value, Then with javascript you grab the value of the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be permanent for a user, you should store it in your database. You should do that by making a call to your server. You can use ajax for that. Using jquery's ajax's function makes it really easy.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You should post to your sever using ajax and change the background color in the database. If you do not want to have to refresh the page, you should then use javascript to change the background color.

Again, jQuery makes this really easy... $('element').css('background-color','color');

Answer (score 0):

Do you try create a simple *< button **onclick='javascript:myfunction(); return false;'**>test < /button>* ?

and you implement what you want inside **'myFunction()'**

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage.

Assign the value in hidden field color. Just pass the color in url `http://mysite.nl/test.php?value=red`.

HTML

```
 <form>
      <a id="change-bg" href="#"> click</a>
      <input type="hidden" name="color" value="<?=(!empty($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : '')?>"/>
    </form>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        if (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined" && typeof localStorage.bgColour !== 'undefined' ) {
            $('body').css({'background' : localStorage.bgColour});
        }
        $('#change-bg').click(function(){
            $('body').css({'background' : $('[name="color"]').val()})
            localStorage.bgColour = $('[name="color"]').val();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```